# PLC Fanuc 90-30 как получить данные?

Tags: микроконтроллеры, zabbix

Есть ПО поставляемое производителем I\O Server GE Fanuc Host Communications (HCS). Я так понимаю, это приложение которое получает данные с контроллера и по DDE передает другой программе в Windows.

Вопрос: Как своими силами получить данные с контроллера? Я хочу избавиться от ПО производителя и соединиться, а также считывать данные с контроллера самостоятельно (разработав своё ПО).

**P.S.**  А вообще, суть в том, что хочу напрямую считывать данные с контроллера в zabbix (или другой системы мониторинга).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, приложение от PLC Fanuc, которое опрашивает данные PLC, использует DDE Server. Сделал DDE client, получаю данные и через socket отправляю данные zabbix